# Specified Cast Invalid Byte to int

Tags: c#, linq, casting, int, byte

I'm trying to cast a list of byte to a list of ints.

My List of bytes only contains one value 11.

```
tmpMarketRights = AllMarketRights.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

11 should be able to be casted to an INT does anyone know why this cast is invalid, and the shortest way to cast a list of bytes to a list of int?

Comment: By "invalid" you mean? What is the exception or the compilation error or the problem you are facing?

Comment: Its a linq function that all the information it gave me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
AllMarketRights.Select(x => (int)x).ToList();
```

To understand why `Cast<int>` produces an exception, we can look into its implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) { 
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource; 
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj; 
}
```

As we can see the `CastIterator` does not try to cast `byte` to `int` (where numeric explicit cast can be applied), but `object` (where unbox actually should happens, and boxed `byte` can not be unboxed as `int`).

Answer (score 5):

***Reason of this exception?***

Firstly, let's try this:

```
 byte myByte = 11;
 object myObject = myByte;
 int x = (int)myObject; // Exception will be thrown here
```

As you see, `InvalidCastException` will be thrown. Because, ***a boxed value*** can only be unboxed to a variable of the ***exact same type***.

Now, let's see what is `Cast()` doing. You can look at the implementation of this method [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec). As you see, it will return `CastIterator`. And [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365) is the implementation of the `CastIterator`:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) 
{
     foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

As you see, it doesn't cast `byte` to `int`, but `object` to `int`. The reason of this is that, `Cast` is an extension method for `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(
    this IEnumerable source
)
```

---

So use one of these ways:

```
 var tmpMarketRights = AllMarketRights.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
 var tmpMarketRights = AllMarketRights.Select(x => (int)x).ToList();
```

Comment: You can cast `byte` to `int` without problem.

Comment: why does boxing work on the select  as seen in ie's example (x => (int)x)

Comment: @Space, there is no boxing in `(x => (int)x) `, Boxing would involve a conversion between value type and reference type. `Cast` is throwing the exception because of boxing in `foreach (object obj in source)` , where a `byte` type is first converted to `object` and then later `int` in `return (TResult)obj`.

Comment: @Space As Habib stated, there is not any boxing operation. Because, both `int` and `byte` are value types.